nnunetv2 been stuck preprocessed dataset
there are 704 graphs in our dataset when we use command nnUnetV2_plan_and_preprocess -d 201 --verify__integrity  The program is stuck in enter image description here immobility.but when we reduce numeber to 600 the program can be run .How to solve this problem?
enter image description here
I want the program to handle the complete dataset

i have rosolve this problem A deadlock occurred while loading the dataset with multiple threads, and the thread count should be modified
